# how to set Sublime Text to default preference?

Tags: sublimetext3

I would like to remove all changes made to my preference and set all my preferences to default. Made some changes that I don't remember and would like to start from the default settings. I prefer not to uninstall my sublime and reinstall if there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is open **`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings-User`**, completely erase its contents, save the empty file, and restart Sublime. This will revert all your settings to the defaults.

If you have plugins installed that you want to get rid of, you can revert Sublime to a *completely* fresh state by exiting the program completely (**`Sublime Text 2 -> Quit`**), then deleting `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2`. This will recreate the state of the program when you first installed it.